# Grouped bar plot with categorical column count

Tags: python

I have this dataframe that has many columns, 2 of them are y and poutcome. Both of them are categorical data. I make a grouped bar plot based on y with sub bar plot poutcome. I tried to create a group by that results this

```
y    poutcome
no   failure      427
     other        159
     success       46
     unknown     3368
yes  failure       63
     other         38
     success       83
     unknown      337
```

Based on that grouped by dataframe, I thought it will result to a graph that looks like this, the legend and the colored bars will be failure,success,other and unknown and they will be grouped by yes and no (in example graph, 4 and 5 would be yes and no). You got the gist.

[image: g1]

The group by is this `bank.groupby(['y','poutcome'])['poutcome'].count()` But instead shows like above, mine show like this

[image]

How do I make it like the first graph? The bars represents the poutcome and they are grouped by y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the dataframe that I used initally:

```
     y poutcome  count
0   no  failure    427
1   no    other    159
2   no  success     46
3   no  unknown   3368
4  yes  failure     63
5  yes    other     38
6  yes  success     83
7  yes  unknown    337
```

You should be able to get this from your `groupby` by setting `as_index=False`

You can then use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to arrange the values for plotting:

```py
df.pivot(index="poutcome", columns="y", values="count")
# y           no  yes
# poutcome           
# failure    427   63
# other      159   38
# success     46   83
# unknown   3368  337

# and plot that:
df.pivot(index="poutcome", columns="y", values="count").plot.bar()
```

[image]

Alternatively to have `poutcome` in the legend swap the index and columns parameters:

```py
df.pivot(index="y", columns="poutcome", values="count").plot.bar()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105005/plotting-bar-chart-of-categorical-values-for-each-group

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to just [**`unstack(level=1)`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) before plotting:

```py
grouped.unstack(level=1).plot.bar()
```