# Plotting bar chart of categorical values for each group

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe that I want to group and then to plot (barplot) based on value_counts.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['jan', 'jan', 'jan', 'jan', 'feb', 'feb', 'feb', 'feb'],
                  'value': ['low', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 'medium', 'high', 'high', 'medium']})
                  
print(df)
```

I want to have months on the X-axis (in this case only `jan` and `feb`) and bars of values for each month on Y-axis. Hight of the bars should depend of count of specific category.
For example, for 'jan' low=2, high=1, medium=1

I have tried:

```
sns.countplot(x = 'date', hue = 'value', data = df.melt())
```

But this is my error:

```
ValueError: Could not interpret input 'date'
```

This can be done with `matplotlib` or `seaborn`

Comment: `sns.countplot(x='date', hue='value', data=df)`?

Comment: Thanks, please post the answer.  the only problem that I have is ordering. 
In my dataset I have all 12 months, and all data is in order, but when I apply your answer, on the graph my month names are all over the place.

Comment: Also, is there a way to change colour of the graphs. high=red, medium=yellow and low = green

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sns.countplot` to count items from the original dataframe. You can use `hue=` to separate out the `value` column. `order=` can fix an order on the x-values. Similarly, `hue_order=` can set an order for the hue categories. (Default, the order of appearance in the dataframe is used.) `palette=` can among others be a dictionary to assign a specific color to a specific category.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['jan', 'jan', 'jan', 'jan', 'feb', 'feb', 'feb', 'feb'],
                   'value': ['low', 'low', 'high', 'medium', 'medium', 'high', 'high', 'medium']})

sns.set()
ax = sns.countplot(data=df, x='date', hue='value',
                   # order=['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec'],
                   order=['jan', 'feb'], hue_order=['low', 'medium', 'high'],
                   palette={'low': 'limegreen', 'medium': 'gold', 'high': 'crimson'})
ax.set_xlabel('')  # optionally remove 'date' label, as it is clear from the ticklabels
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.countplot with x and hue ordering]